# Looking for ReactJS barcode scanner with focus option / feature for Mobile Web

Tags: reactjs, mobile, camera, barcode-scanner, autofocus

I've been trying to find a React scanner module with the ability to focus the camera. This is for a barcode scanner for Mobile web.
I have tried multiple React solutions and spent days searching but the closest I have come is https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-webcam-barcode-scanner.

However this does not work as the camera remains out of focus and there are no options to focus the camera. Also, I have seen multiple ReactNative implementations, but I require a ReactJS solution.

I appreciate any help / suggestions.